# What old wide angle lens should I use for reverse macro?

Tags: macro, canon-5d-mark-ii, reverse-mount, macro-converter

I want to expirement with a reversed wide angle lens for high magnification photography.  I would prefer an older lens where I can set the F-Stop manually on the lens itself.

I use a Canon 5D Mark II.  To reverse the lens I should just get a reverse ring adapter for Canon and should be good to go?  Most lens have the same thread size right?

Would I have any problems with an old FD lens for example.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any lens from any manufacturer. I use a 40 year old PK-mount Rikonon 50mm 1.7 lens on my Nikon (manual aperture rings are a great help when reversing). The wider the angle the bigger the magnification.

Lens filter threads *do* vary in size, so make sure the ring you buy fits the lens you plan to use. Check out the [Photo SE blog post on reversing rings](http://photo.blogoverflow.com/2011/07/take-macro-shots-like-this-for-less-than-the-cost-of-a-pizza/) for more info and tips.

Comment: Great article, so any old lens with a manual apperture ring should be OK? Canon FD lens seems to have some levers on the mount also, do you think it is the same as what you are talking about in your article?

Thanks

Comment: Yes - the aperture ring is a bonus, not a must. I haven't looked at an FD lens but basically any lens that lets you open the aperture somehow will work.

Comment: Any way to retain flash E-TTL?  I would probably only use flash lighting anyway.  So would set the apperture and shutter speed manually but it would be nice if the flash output was automatic.  Any way to do that?  Thanks

Comment: No, there's no CPU contact between the lens and the camera. You'll have to use manual flash.

Comment: Tested my new reversed lens with a Canon ETTL flash, no need to put it in manual.  ETTL worked fine even if the camera reports an aperture of 0.

Comment: Nice one :) Well done.